# error of undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and I have this `no method error`

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Profile Page for <%= @item.id %></h1>
<p><%= @item.content %></p>
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @item = Item.new
    end

    def create
        item = Item.new(item_Params)
        if item.save
            redirect_to user_path(item.user)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

private

def item_Params
    params.require(:item).permit(:user_id, :content)
end
end
```

I want to create a show page for `items/:id` and I want to be able to view each item by their id, how should I create it?

Comment: where is the `show` method?

Comment: how do i create the show method, what parameters do i have in it

Comment: @AlbertConrad: RoR follows a convention: name of view is same as name of action in a folder with name same as controller. In your code you have pasted code for show page, but I cannot see code for show action in your controller. 
Also please paste stacktrace of error in your question.

Comment: even absense of show method do not bother because rails prefer convention over configuration but @item is not defined even in any filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is my show page

Show page for which resource? Is it `/users/:id` (since you're redirecting to it) or `items/:id`? Anyway, you need to define `@item` in show action of corresponding controller. If you add more information about corresponding controller and user-item association, I can help you with it

UPDATE:

Just add to the ItemsController

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

Make sure that you have a line `resources :items` inside `routes.rb`.

I think you need to read more about rails controllers in [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

BTW: it is a convention in ruby to use snake_case for method naming. Should be 'item_params', not 'item_Params'

Comment: the show page is for `items/:id` i want to view each item by their id, how will i create it

Comment: @AlbertConrad, I updated the answer. Sorry, forgot to notify you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add show action which is for show page and You find the item corresponding its Id. so you just write below action in your controller.

```
def show
 @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can find your item in your Item model using find method.